# KeyedCollection with enum key type will not index by int

Tags: c#, .net

I have classes

```
public class FooKeyedCollection : KeyedCollection<FooType,Foo>
{
}

public enum FooType
{
   FooType1,
   FooType2,
   FooType3
}

public Foo
{
   public FooType Type { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

When I add items to my FooKeyedCollection, I can index them by FooType, but when I attempt to index them int, the int is interpretted as the FooType enum.  As a result, it leads to a confusing error, i.e.

```
public static void main()
{
   FooKeyedCollection fkc = new FooKeyedCollection();

   Foo myFoo = new Foo();
   myFoo.Type = FooType.FooType3;
   myFoo.Value = "someValue";

   foo.Add( myFoo );

   Foo myFooByType = foo[FooType.FooType3];
   Foo myFooByIndex = foo[0]; // <-- exception thrown here
}
```

The result of executing this code is an exception when attempting to retrieve the item by integer index.  I hope to expose the FooKeyedCollection as part of a public API, and I want to protect the consumers of this API from this error.  Is there any way that I can modify the FooKeyedCollection class to get proper behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider using the "new" keyword here:

```
public new Foo this[int index]
{
   get
   {
      IList<Foo> self = this;
      return self[index];
   }
   set
   {
       (IList<Foo>)[index] = value;
   }
}
```

This will allow you to index by integer value. Using the enum explicitly will fall back to the KeyedCollection implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a helpful extension method to avoid these cases where the two indexers overlap - it also helps if the key is `int`:

```
static class CollectionUtils
{
    public static TValue GetByIndex<TKey,TValue>
        (this KeyedCollection<TKey, TValue> collection, int index)
    {
        return collection[index];
    }
}
```

then call `fkc.GetByIndex(0)` and it will work fine. Inside the generic method it can *only* resolve `index` to the `int` indexer.

Comment: Personally I think this is the best solution. Aside from anything else, it means you won't go wrong if you end up just using it as a KeyedCollection<FooType,Foo> (where Jeff's solution falls down).

Comment: @Jon - my thoughts exactly ;-p

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that 0 is implicitly convertible to `FooType`. If you use any other number, it'll be fine. If you use this code, it should work too:

```
int index = 0;
Foo myFooByIndex = foo[index];
```

EDIT: Unfortunately casting doesn't help here - the compiler still recognises it as a constant 0.

Comment: I tried casting to (int), but it still resolved as a FooType and threw the exception.